# How is TClientDataSet sending SQL statements on ApplyUpdates

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I am wondering, how the `TClientDataSet` is executing the SQL statment when `ApplyUpdates` is invoked.

If there is more than one record changed, is the update SQL query prepared and sent for each record as single SQL statment or is there maybe a SQL 'script' created and than sent at once to the database?

I mean, is there a performance difference, when I `ApplyUpdates` on very record change in contrast to `ApplyUpdates` for all changes at once?

Answer (score 7):

No SQL is sent from the client, only the delta packet. The provider on the server receives the delta packet and generates insert/update/delete SQL statements based on it. Sending multiple updates in a single request usually leads to better performance.

Comment: Thanks. Does the Provider create for every delta package a single SQL statement? And does he send it one after the other to the database?

Comment: It depends on the provider you use and its options. In case of TDataSetProvider, it also depends on the dataset. For details, see the source code (start with the Provider unit).

Comment: you should use sql monitor to preview how the provider build Delete/Update/Insert sql statements...